# Do Boots of Teleportation allow you to take allies with you?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, teleportation

[Boots of Teleportation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bootsofTeleportation) says:

> Any character wearing this footwear may teleport three times per day, exactly as if he had cast the spell of the same name.

[The spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) says (highlighting mine):

> This spell instantly transports you to a designated destination, which may be as distant as 100 miles per caster level. Interplanar travel is not possible. You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load. **You may also bring one additional willing Medium or smaller creature (carrying gear or objects up to its maximum load) or its equivalent (see below) per three caster levels.**

Same thing with [Helm of Teleportation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#helmofTeleportation). Both items have a CL of 9th, so that would mean 3 allies according to the spell. Do these items allow you to teleport the entire party of 4 allies (wearer / caster + 3 medium creatures) or only yourself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, you can**. The *[boots](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bootsofTeleportation)* state that you use them exactly as if you had used the spell *[teleportation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm)*. That means you gain all effects of the spell, exactly as if you had cast it on yourself, including the ability to take people with you.

As for how many people you can take, the spell allows for one medium creature (or lower) per three caster levels. If we check the boots we see they have a caster level of 9th, and so you can take 3 medium creatures or less with you, allowing you to take the entire party of 4 medium creatures. However, beware of encumbrance limits when hauling back treasure from a dungeon. You will probably want Heward's Handy Haversacks, Portable Holes, and similar carrying aids, to make sure you are not heavily encumbered.

Answer (score 2):

No, the items give you (the “character wearing this footwear”) the **effect** of *teleportation* as if you had cast it (read: you “may teleport,” which is a summary of *teleportation*’s effect), but only you. They do not give you the ability to cast it as if it were the spell (i.e. choose the targeting yourself).